# Filtering list of items with JQuery checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a set of two different checkboxes; price, and category.

Initially, I want the whole list of results to show, but then as filters are applied, the list changes, and then when filters are removed, or all removed, the list adjusts.

I'm using JQuery to filter the results, but I can't seem to get it so that when there are no checkboxes ticked all products show, and for example if none of the price ones are ticked, but the instrument one in category is, all the instruments show. They are identified by the class tag within the `<li>` tag, which in my code, is set from a JSON file, but in the JSFiddle, I've just put some example test data.

I've created a JSFiddle, but it doesn't seem to be running, but the exact same code runs on my laptop.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#price :checkbox").click(function() {
    $("li").hide();
    $("#price :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).val()).show();
    });
  });

  $("#category :checkbox").click(function() {
    $("li").hide();
    $("#category :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      $("." + $(this).val()).show();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="price">
  <p id="fHeader">Price</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="p1" id="p1" />£0 - £5
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="p2" id="p2" />£5 - £10
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="p3" id="p3" />£10 - £50
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="p4" id="p4" />£50 - £100
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="p5" id="p5" />£100 - £500
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="p6" id="p6" />£500 - £1000
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="p7" id="p7" />£1000 +
  <br>
</section>

<section id="category">
  <p id="fHeader">Category</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="instruments" id="instruments" />Instruments
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="sheetmusic" id="sheet-music" />Sheet Music
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="accessories" id="accessories" />Accessories
  <br>
</section>

<article id="products">
  <ul id="productList">
    <li class="instruments p5 buffet woodwind clarinet">Buffet B12 Clarinet £400</li>
    <li class="instruments p7 yamaha woodwind clarinet">Yamaha Clarinet £1700</li>
    <li class="instruments p6 trevorjames woodwind alto-saxophone">Trevor James Alto Saxophone £700</li>
    <li class="instruments p3 aulos woodwind recorder">Aulos Recorder £16</li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

Any help as to how to approach it from here would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Probably because you haven't selected Jquery from the dropdown box on the left in jsfiddle :/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y1w1rzrL/2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use data attributes instead of a class. This means you can group your checkbox click into one function. See below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#filters :checkbox').click(function () {
        if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length) {
            $('li').hide();
            $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
                $('li[data-' + $(this).prop('name') + '*="' + $(this).val() + '"]').show();
            });
        } else {
            $("li").show();
        }
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="filters">
    <section id="price">
        <p id="fHeader">Price</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="p1" id="p1" />£0 - £5
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="p2" id="p2" />£5 - £10
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="p3" id="p3" />£10 - £50
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="p4" id="p4" />£50 - £100
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="p5" id="p5" />£100 - £500
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="p6" id="p6" />£500 - £1000
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="p7" id="p7" />£1000 +
        <br/>
    </section>
    <section id="category">
        <p id="fHeader">Category</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="instruments" id="instruments" />Instruments
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="sheetmusic" id="sheet-music" />Sheet Music
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="accessories" id="accessories" />Accessories
        <br/>
    </section>
</article>
<article id="products">
    <ul id="productList">
        <li data-price="p5" data-category="instruments">Buffet B12 Clarinet £400</li>
        <li data-price="p7" data-category="instruments">Yamaha Clarinet £1700</li>
        <li data-price="p6" data-category="instruments">Trevor James Alto Saxophone £700</li>
        <li data-price="p3" data-category="instruments">Aulos Recorder £16</li>
    </ul>
</article>
```

I also notice you have two `id="fHeader"`. This is bad, real bad...

---

### EDIT FOR CORRECT AND/OR SEARCHING

This is a bit more complex. It creates an array of values and an array of types. We then loop through each LI, to loop through each type, to loop through each value (loop within a loop within a loop, yikes!), with the basis that all types need at least one correct value in order to display the LI.

I would also make sure your values are distinct by putting a `;` or something before and after them, because for example "piano" will also match "grand-piano" however ";piano;" will not match ";grand-piano;"

```js
$('#filters input:checkbox').click(function () {
    if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length) {
        var arrSelected = []; // Create Array of Values
        var arrTypes = []; // Create Array of Types
        $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
            if (arrSelected[$(this).prop('name')] == undefined) {
                arrSelected[$(this).prop('name')] = [];
            }
            arrSelected[$(this).prop('name')].push($(this).val());
            if ($.inArray($(this).prop('name'), arrTypes) < 0) {
                arrTypes.push($(this).prop('name'));
            }
        });
        $('li').each(function() {
            $(this).hide();   
            var intKeyCount = 0;
            for (key in arrTypes) { // AND (check count of matching types)
                var blnFound = false;
                for (val in arrSelected[arrTypes[key]]) { // OR (check one of values matches type)
                    if ($(this).attr('data-' + arrTypes[key]).indexOf(arrSelected[arrTypes[key]][val]) > -1) {                       
                        blnFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (blnFound) {
                    intKeyCount++;
                }
            }
            if (intKeyCount > 0 && intKeyCount != arrTypes.length - 1) {
                $(this).show();   
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("li").show();
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="filters">
    <section id="price">
        <p id="fHeader">Price</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="p1" id="p1" />£0 - £5
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="p2" id="p2" />£5 - £10
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="p3" id="p3" />£10 - £50
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="p4" id="p4" />£50 - £100
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="p5" id="p5" />£100 - £500
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="p6" id="p6" />£500 - £1000
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="price" value="p7" id="p7" />£1000 +
        <br/>
    </section>
    <section id="category">
        <p id="fHeader">Category</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="instruments" id="instruments" />Instruments
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="sheetmusic" id="sheet-music" />Sheet Music
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="accessories" id="accessories" />Accessories
        <br/>
    </section>
</article>
<article id="products">
    <ul id="productList">
        <li data-price="p5" data-category="instruments">Buffet B12 Clarinet £400</li>
        <li data-price="p7" data-category="instruments">Yamaha Clarinet £1700</li>
        <li data-price="p6" data-category="instruments">Trevor James Alto Saxophone £700</li>
        <li data-price="p3" data-category="instruments">Aulos Recorder £16</li>
    </ul>
</article>
```

Comment: The two ID's being the same is because I copy and pasted and forgot to change them, bad move on my part for sure. Just utilising the code at the moment to see if I can apply it to mine

Comment: Ah, one thing I've just come across, is if I select one price, and then instruments, it then shows them all again, doesn't take into account that only one price band is selected?

Comment: Shouldn't do, but I'll have a look once I get back to a computer this evening @Navvy

Comment: @Navvy I understand the problem with the previous code now. I've updated the answer with some code that should do the objective. Had a real mind bender on how to do it, but it's not pretty. If there's a better method, I can't think of it :/.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that was something I was attempting and ending up with was loops within loops but couldn't get it to work, and couldn't think of an easier method either as it required comparing to what was already ticke . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before each loop show all list items and check how many checkboxes are checked, if the value is 0 do nothing.